# How do I test if the current logged in user's id is in a list of id's

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have this question model:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="created at")
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="updated at")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "question"
        verbose_name_plural = "questions"
        db_table = "questions"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.body
```

and then I have this question feeling model which is just for someone to like a question:

```
class QuestionFeeling(models.Model):
    like = "like"
    feelings = [
        (like , "like"),
    ]
    feeling = models.CharField(max_length=15,choices=feelings, default=like)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='feelings')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="question_feelings")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="created at")
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="updated at")
    
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['question', 'user']
        verbose_name = "Question feeling"
        verbose_name_plural = "Question feelings"
        db_table = "question_feeling"

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.feeling)
```

I am using Django rest framework and I would like to see if a user already likes a question. I don't want to do a serializer method field where the database needs to be queried twice. I would just like to see if the logged in user's id matches any of the feelings' user ids

On the front end the array for feelings that appear for each question looks like this:

```
feelings: Array [ {…} ]

​​​​0: Object { id: 1, feeling: "like", created_at: "2023-02-13T04:21:43.323313Z", … }
​​​​​created_at: "2023-02-13T04:21:43.323313Z"
​​feeling: "like"
​​​​id: 1
​​​​question: 14
​​​​updated_at: "2023-02-13T04:21:43.323358Z"
​​​​user: 33
```

and here is my serializer method on the question serializer:

```
    def get_liked(self, obj):
        request = self.context.get('request', None)
        if request:
            loggedUser = self.context["request"].user.id  
            for feeling in obj.feelings:
                if loggedUser == feeling.user:
                    return True
```

When I try and run it I get an error

```
TypeError: 'RelatedManager' object is not iterable
```

It's an array is it not? Why is it not iterable or is the related manager referring to something else?

How else can I check if the logged in user's id is in the array of feelings?

Answer (score 1):

`obj.feelings` is `RelatedManager` and `obj.feelings.all()` is `QuerySet`

To check if current user has assigned object in this QuerySet you should filter it and check if QuestionFeeling with request user assigned exists:

```
def get_liked(self, obj):
    request = self.context.get('request', None)
    if request:
        loggedUser = self.context["request"].user  
        return obj.feelings.filter(user=loggedUser).exists()
```

Answer (score -1):

In the template, you should use `obj.feelings.all` to get all the `feelings`.

Comment: Really not what I asked but thanks for trying